# How to get list of LDAP schema attributes that use syntaxID 2.5.5.16 Long-Integer to store 64-bit NT FILE TIME (time-interval) value

Tags: active-directory, ldap, schema

is there any way to query LDAP schema attributes that use syntaxID 2.5.5.16 (Long-Integer) to store 64-bit NT FILE TIME ([time-interval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/s-interval)) value?
I know some of them like: pwdLastSet, lastLogon, badPasswordTime.
but how can I get all of those defined attributes in schema by query against schema configuration?

Comment: Do you want to query the AD schema to find all attribute that use that type? Or do you want to query AD for users based on one of those (for example, all users with a certain lastLogon date)?

Comment: query against schema to find all attributes that use that type.

Comment: Microsoft is using syntaxID 2.5.5.16 for timestamp and other attributes that need long int number like size in KB or latitude longitude. I specifically want to get attributes that are storing timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to find all of those exactly. The interval type is used for non-dates too. You'll see in the [documentation for the `mS-SQL-Status` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-ms-sql-status) for example, that the "Syntax" is "Interval", but it's not a date. The Interval type is really just a number. There is nothing in the schema that tells you how that number is used.

The best you can do is find all the attributes of Interval type, then find an object that has that attribute populated and try to convert it to a date and see what happens. But most of the attributes of that type aren't really used, so won't have any object that has the attribute populated.

I don't know what language you're using, but in C# that would look something like this (change the DN in the first line to reflect your domain):

```
var schema = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com");
var attributeSearch = new DirectorySearcher(schema) {
    Filter = "(&(objectClass=attributeSchema)(attributeSyntax=2.5.5.16))",
    PropertiesToLoad = { "lDAPDisplayName" }
};

using (var results = attributeSearch.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
        var attributeName = (string) result.Properties["lDAPDisplayName"][0];
        var search = new DirectorySearcher {
            Filter = $"({attributeName}=*)",
            PropertiesToLoad = { attributeName }
        };
        try {
            var hasAttribute = search.FindOne();
            if (hasAttribute != null) {
                try {
                    var attributeValue = (long) hasAttribute.Properties[attributeName][0];
                    var asDate = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(attributeValue);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{attributeName}: Is a date ({asDate})");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{attributeName}: Not a date ({e.Message})");
                }
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine($"{attributeName}: Could not find an object with this attribute");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{attributeName}: Error searching ({e.Message})");
        }
    }
}
```

However, even that is not entirely reliable since `0` is a valid file-time date.

Comment: this is too general and includes attributes that doesn't have 64-bit NT FILE TIME (time-interval) value. Microsoft is using syntaxID 2.5.5.16 for timestamp and other attributes that need long int number like size in KB or latitude longitude. I specifically want to get attributes that are storing timestamp.

Comment: @SaeidOstad I see. There is no reliable way to do that. I've updated my answer with the best way you can do it, but it's not 100%. AD simply doesn't tell you how the values are used.

Comment: I was hoping to get a solution with more accuracy. thanks for the solution, it will work for most of the cases but not for all.